# NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-1.9.3

After a reboot of my vm, any time I attempt to access any data I get this error. I am using Rails 3.2.3, and Mongodb w/ Mongoid. This is my first project using MongoDB and Mongoid and I am fairly certain the issue has something to do with it. It appears that Mongo is started and running. The full error message is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:118:in `block in refresh'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:125:in `each'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:125:in `refresh'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:78:in `nodes'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/cluster.rb:187:in `with_secondary'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/session/context.rb:104:in `with_node'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/session/context.rb:43:in `query'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/moped-1.2.5/lib/moped/query.rb:109:in `first'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/mongoid-3.0.6/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:201:in `first'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/mongoid-3.0.6/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18:in `first'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/mongoid-3.0.6/lib/mongoid/finders.rb:119:in `first'
from (irb):3
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@applicationName/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your mongoid.yml has been overwritten. Try doing a `rails g mongoid:config` and trying again. Cheers.